# maito command in anchor tag is not working anymore

Tags: html, mailto

```
href="mailto:johndoe@xyz.com"
```

The above code snippet on an anchor tag should open a default mail client on any system but now it's going to an external URL "https://sso.secureserver.net/?realm=pass&app=ox&saas=0&region=am2"

You can try with any of the old web pages you've built, It goes to this URL all of a sudden.

Does anyone know why?

Its really weired

Comment: Is your default mail client set to https://sso.secureserver.net? And what is your website built with, is the above snippet also the generated markup? Can you provide more info?

Comment: Hey @Keimeno, Thanks for the quick response.

I Never thought it from that angle, I feel dumb lol. How do I check the default mail client? I'm using a Mac book pro

Comment: Please provide your snippet so we can replicate the error and solve

Comment: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201607#:~:text=Open%20the%20Mail%20app.,%E2%80%9DDefault%20email%20reader%E2%80%9D%20menu.

Comment: Thanks, @Keimeno. I changed it to apple mail and it's working.

It was opening the URL since chrome was set as the default mail client for my mac

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as most of you guys said it was configured in my mail setting's / prefrences. So google chrome was set as default mail client and it went to the godaddy URL.

I followed https://support.apple.com/en-in/HT201607 to get it fixed and everthing is working smooth now! Thanks Everyone!

**How to change your default email app**

1. Make sure that the other email app is installed. Although you might be able to use a web browser for email (webmail), a web browser isn't an email app.
2. Open the Mail app.
3. Choose Mail > Preferences, then click General.
4. Choose an email app from the ”Default email reader” menu.

Answer (score 0):

It must be a redirection set from your browser/OS. Check what is your default email client in browser.